# How to group buttons in different forms tags in Bootstrap

Tags: forms, button, twitter-bootstrap

How do you group buttons within different form tags together in Twitter's Bootstrap?

Right now what I get is:

```
<div class="btn-group"> 
    <!--More button-->
    <form action="search.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="some name" value="same value">
    <button style="float:left" class="btn" type="submit"><i class="icon-search"></i> More</button>
    </form>
    <!--Edit button-->
    <form action="edit_product.php" method="post">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  name="product_number" value="some value"><i class="icon-cog icon-white"></i> Edit</button>
     </form>
     <!--delete button-->
     <button data-toggle="modal" href="#error_delete" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i> Delete</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you'd rather not use scripting you can use hidden inputs (or any inline element, such as `<i></i>`) to create the proper first:child and last:child relationships:

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/TRjEp)**

```
<form class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn">Button One</button>
    <input type="hidden" class="btn"><!-- fake sibling to right -->
</form>

<form class="btn-group">
    <i></i><!-- fake sibling to left -->
    <button class="btn">Button Two</button>
</form>
```

In the latest versions of Bootstrap 2 I did have to add one bit of CSS override:

```
form.btn-group + form.btn-group {margin-left: -5px;}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use JQuery to achieve it.

```
<form id="form1" action="search.php" method="POST">
 <input type="hidden" name="some name" value="same value">
</form>

<form id="form2" action="edit_product.php" method="post">
 </form>

<div class="btn-group"> 
 <button id="more" style="float:left" class="btn" type="submit"><i class="icon-search"></i>  More</button><!--More button-->
 <button id="edit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  name="product_number" value="some value"><i class="icon-cog icon-white"></i> Edit</button>
 <button data-toggle="modal" href="#error_delete" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i> Delete</button>    
</div>
```

And with JQuery:

```
$("#more").click(function() {
    $("#form1").submit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Wrap the `btn-group`s in a `btn-toolbar`

If you are using Bootstrap v4 or newer:

```html
<div class=btn-toolbar>
    <form class=btn-group>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Button One</button>
        <i></i>
    </form>
    <form class=btn-group>
        <i></i>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Button Two</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/87h14enw/))

As of v4, `btn-toolbar` does not add any extra margins to a `btn-group`; on the contrary, you actually have to add `m*` classes yourself if you need any spacing between groups in a toolbar.

If you are using an older version of Bootstrap (<=v3), apply [@isherwood's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428385/how-to-group-buttons-in-different-forms-tags-in-bootstrap/17603157#17603157).